# (Softlayer Api) How to get volume status for eVault?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I tried to add mask value with 'volumeStatus', but it seems that it allways returns null.

```
Service service = Evault.service(client, Long.parseLong(storageId));
service.withMask().volumeStatus();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This request can help you:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getEvaultNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask(SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)[agentStatuses]

Method: GET
```

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Version6)